# iPhone: Random moving bubbles animation using coregraphics?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm developing an app which will show 10-15 bubbles is moving around the screen randomly and will stay inside the screen. In fact they are buttons and when user will click on any-one it will show a random image.

Now my problem is, how should i animate smoothly these bubbles as random moving buttons? i have tried with timer and uiview animation but they are not working well or i'm missing something.

Plz plz help me.....

Regards...
Benzamin.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Core Animation for your app.
The ["Move Me" sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/index.html) does almost exactly what you need.

Apple also has a good introduction to CA over [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html).